# Internal microphone: no sound level in pavucontrol but record with arecord, pacat -r and audacity work - Skype doesn't

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, microphone, pulse-audio

My internal microphone is not working in Skype. The first thing I did was checking if the microphone was found by pulseaudio. I opened up pavucontrol and recognized that the microphone was there but the sound level bar does not move when speaking into the microphone. The microphone is not muted. I also checked this in alsamixer.
The sound level bar moves for the monitor device when playing music.

BUT:
pacat -r > test,
arecord -vv -fdat test.wav
and audacity record
work fine.

I'm under Ubuntu linux 12.04 64bit with kernel 3.5.0-40 and pulseaudio 1.1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

The problem was that pulseaudio saw my mono microphone as a stereo one. I just had to mute one channel (click on the lock to disable one channel to have the same volume as the other one). Additionally Skype turned down the microphone volume automatically to nearly 0. I disabled this in the Skype audio preferences so I have a fixed microphone volume.

Tipp:
Try not to adjust the microphone volume with the ubuntu sound preferences as this would turn the microphone back to a stereo one.

Comment: The same issue appeared on a Lenovo ideapad 310 under Linux Mint 19.1.  I was looking for a permanent solution to configure the build-in microphone as mono, but still can not find anything.  Changing the microphone level in the Linux Mint configuration panel breaks the workaround.